# Flutter detect hidden-camera

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using SafeArea in flutter, But in `galaxy-s10-plus` my view is under camera
Both `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` and `MediaQuery.of(context).padding` are zero

How can I detect camera padding in flutter?

[image]